# Android EditText fading out overflow text

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to achieve an effect similar to what's shown here:
https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/DkKgJ

Screenshot of rendered text:
[image: Screenshot]

I have tried the following:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/field_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="This is a very long headline, maybe even too long for this box."/>
    <View
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_to_white"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The `bg_gradient_to_white` is a gradient from transparent (#00000000) to solid white (#FFFFFFFF). However, this doesn't seem to work, and I don't notice the right edge being faded at all. Alternatively I would be also fine if the EditText would allow the ellipses being shown. For the example above, I would be "This is a very long headline, maybe ...".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically try this:

```
mNameTextView.measure(0, 0);
Shader textShader=new LinearGradient(0, 0, mNameTextView.getMeasuredWidth(), 0,
new int[]{Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE},
new float[]{0, 1}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
mNameTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

this works for me